# jQuery DataTable Undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatables

I have two DataTables defined in $(document).ready() as follows:

```
oProdTable1 = $('#productstable1').dataTable( {...} );
oProdTable2 = $('#productstable2').dataTable( {...} );
```

Outside of $(document).ready(), I try to reload them. When I put a breakpoint in the following success function, I find that oProdTable1 is defined, but oProdTable2 is undefined:

```
function addProduct(productLine) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax-add-product.php',
        data: { productLine: productLine},
        success: function(data) {
            oProdTable1.fnReloadAjax();
            oProdTable2.fnReloadAjax();
        }
    }); 
}
```

I can't find a difference between the definitions of these two tables. I also am wondering why oProdTable1 does not need to be declared with "var", yet is defined. Any ideas?

EDIT: I should note that oProdTable1 appears correctly, but oProdTable2 requires me to click to sort by a column for the rows to appear.

EDIT2: I have tried putting addProduct() inside $(document).ready(). oProdTable1 is still undefined and oProdTable2 is still undefined. I tried putting oProdTable2 before oProdTable1 and now oProdTable1 doesn't even load and both tables are undefined!

EDIT3: Every DataTable in the code after oProdTable2 does not load and is undefined. I compared the oProdTable1 and oProdTable2 code using the Notepad++ compare plugin and cannot find any major differences such as missing braces that I think could cause this.

EDIT4: Here is the code for oProdTable2, which seems to be problematic:

```
oProdTable2 = $('#productstable2').dataTable( {
    "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
    "aoColumnDefs":[
    {"aTargets":[0],"bSearchable":false,"bVisible": false},
    {"aTargets":[1],"sWidth":"60px"},
    {"aTargets":[2],"sWidth":"200px"},
    {"aTargets":[3],"sWidth":"300px"},
    {"aTargets":[4],"sWidth":"60px"},
    {"aTargets":[5],"sWidth":"60px"},
    {"aTargets":[6],"sWidth":"60px"},
    {"aTargets":[7],"sWidth":"60px"},
    {"aTargets":[8],"sWidth":"60px"},
    {"aTargets":[9],"sWidth":"60px"},
    {"aTargets":[10],"sWidth":"60px"},
    {"aTargets":[11],"sWidth":"60px"},

    { "sClass": "usa", "aTargets": [ 4, 5 ] },
    { "sClass": "can", "aTargets": [ 6, 7 ] },
    { "sClass": "lat", "aTargets": [ 8, 9 ] },
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": 100, //sets item limit for table
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bSortCellsTop": true,
    //"bStateSave": true,
    "bSortClasses": false,
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">C<"fg-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr ui-helper-clearfix"lfr>t<"fg-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-bl ui-corner-br ui-helper-clearfix"ip>',
    "oTableTools": {
        "sRowSelect": "single",
        "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf",
        "aButtons": 
        [   
            //"Add Product" button

            {
                "sExtends":    "text",
                "sButtonText": "Add Product",                  
                "fnClick": function ( nButton, oConfig, oFlash ) {

                    addProduct("2");
                }
            },  
            {
                    "sExtends":    "collection",
                    "sButtonText": "Export",
                    "aButtons":    [    "copy","print","csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
            }
         ]

    },
    'sAjaxSource': 'ajax-getproductstable.php',

    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {

       aoData.push( { "name": "productLine", "value": "2" } );

    },      
    "fnInitComplete": function() {
            var oSettings = $('#productstable2').dataTable().fnSettings();
            for ( var i=0 ; i<oSettings.aoPreSearchCols.length ; i++ ){
                if(oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[i].sSearch.length>0){
                $("thead input")[i-1].value = oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[i].sSearch;
                $("thead input")[i-1].className = "activefilter";   }
            }
    },
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {

        var id = aData[0];


        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[1]).addClass("editable").addClass("ref"); 
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[2]).addClass("edit_area").addClass("name");           
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[3]).addClass("edit_area").addClass("description");            
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[4]).addClass("editable").addClass("price_rtl_usa");           
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[5]).addClass("editable").addClass("price_dlr_usa");           
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[6]).addClass("editable").addClass("price_rtl_can");       
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[7]).addClass("editable").addClass("price_dlr_can");
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[8]).addClass("editable").addClass("price_rtl_lat");       
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[9]).addClass("editable").addClass("price_dlr_lat");       
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[10]).addClass("editable").addClass("ins_val_rtl_usa");
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[11]).addClass("editable").addClass("ins_val_dlr_usa");
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[12]).addClass("editable").addClass("ins_val_rtl_can");
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[13]).addClass("editable").addClass("ins_val_dlr_can");
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[14]).addClass("editable").addClass("net_l");
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[15]).addClass("editable").addClass("net_w");
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[16]).addClass("editable").addClass("net_h");
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[17]).addClass("editable").addClass("net_weight");
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[18]).addClass("editable").addClass("packed_l");
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[19]).addClass("editable").addClass("packed_w");
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[20]).addClass("editable").addClass("packed_h");
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[21]).addClass("editable").addClass("packed_weight");
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[22]).addClass("editable").addClass("customs_cost");
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[23]).addClass("editable").addClass("customs_desc");
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[24]).addClass("editable").addClass("customs_code");
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[25]).addClass("editable").addClass("customs_origin");
        $(this.fnGetTds(nRow)[26]).addClass("edit_area").addClass("note");


        $(nRow).attr("id", id);



        return nRow;
    },
    "fnDrawCallback": function () {


        // CODE FOR EDITABLE INLINES        
        $(".edit_area_w").editable('ajax-edit-product-inline.php', {
            type : 'mce',
            submit : 'OK',
            indicator : "Saving...",
            tooltip : 'Click to edit...',
            width : '500px',
            height : '100px',
            "callback": function( sValue, y ) { 
                $(this).removeClass('empty_edit');
                $("#productstable tr").removeClass("just_edited");
                $(this).parent().addClass("just_edited");
                var aPos = oProdTable2.fnGetPosition( this );
                var update = oProdTable2.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[2], true, true);
            },
            "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
                return {
                    "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
                    "column": oProdTable2.fnGetPosition( this )[2]
                };
            }
        });

        $('.editable').editable('ajax-edit-product-inline.php', {
            event     : "dblclick",
            "callback": function( sValue, y ) { 
                $(this).removeClass('empty_edit');
                $("#productstable tr").removeClass("just_edited");
                $(this).parent().addClass("just_edited");
                var aPos = oProdTable2.fnGetPosition( this );
                var update = oProdTable2.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[2], true, true);
            },
            "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
                return {
                    "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
                    "column": oProdTable2.fnGetPosition( this )[2]
                };
            },
            "height": "14px"
        } );

        $('.edit_area').editable('ajax-edit-product-inline.php', {
            event     : "dblclick",
            type      : "textarea",
            cancel    : 'Cancel',
            submit    : 'OK',
            indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
            "callback": function( sValue, y ) { 
                $(this).removeClass('empty_edit');
                $("#productstable tr").removeClass("just_edited");
                $(this).parent().addClass("just_edited");
                var aPos = oProdTable2.fnGetPosition( this );
                oProdTable2.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[2]);

            },
            "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
                return {
                    "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
                    "column": oProdTable2.fnGetPosition( this )[2]
                };
            },

        } );

        $('.edit_select').editable('ajax-edit-product-inline.php', { 
            event     : "dblclick",
            loaddata: function ( value, settings ) {
                return {
                    "pid": $(this).parent().attr("id")
                };
            },
            loadurl : 'ajax-part-selects.php',
            loadtype: "GET",
            type   : 'select',
            submit : 'OK',
            "callback": function( sValue, y ) { 
                $(this).removeClass('empty_edit');
                $("#productstable tr").removeClass("just_edited");
                $(this).parent().addClass("just_edited");
                var aPos = oProdTable2.fnGetPosition( this );
                oProdTable2.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[2]);

            },
            "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
                return {
                    "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
                    "column": oProdTable2.fnGetPosition( this )[2]
                };
            },
        });



    }
} );

$("#productstable2  .floating_filters input").keyup( function () {
    // Filter on the column (the index) of this element
    oProdTable2.fnFilter( this.value, $(".floating_filters input").index(this)+1 );
    $(this).addClass("activefilter");
} );


$("#productstable2 .floating_filters input").each( function (i) {

    asInitVals[i] = this.value;
} );

$("#productstable2 .floating_filters input").focus( function () {

    if ( $(this).hasClass("search_init"))
    {
        this.className = "";
        this.value = "";
    }
} );

$("#productstable2 .floating_filters input").blur( function (i) {

    if ( this.value == "" )
    {
        $(this).removeClass("activefilter");
        $(this).addClass("search_init");
        this.value = asInitVals[$(".floating_filters input").index(this)];

    }
} );
```

Comment: Are you trying to reload the tables before the document ready has fired? It is possibly a race condition if so.

Comment: No, the tables are visible on the page when the function is called.

Comment: not sure why you are calling them from outside the ready event but it might be better to define this function inside the ready event? are you sure they are visible, do alert(1);

Comment: Do you have multiple $(document).ready() functions? Can you show us full JavaScript code for this page?

Comment: well try keeping `oProdTable2` before to `oProdTable1` i guessyou get `oProdTable1` is undefined . If so fnReloadAjax() is the villian . let me know

Comment: Datatables only requires that the html is correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution! The problem wasn't even with the javascript code, it was with the html. The table with the id "productstable2" had one less "td" than "th". I just needed to add an additional `<td></td>` to the list of "td"s.